# Prism InteractionRequest + MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, prism, mahapps.metro

I would like to create a popup window or dialog with confirmation of choice (OK, Cancel) with WPF Prism + MahApps.Metro

I have created custom Interaction:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding DeleteConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
            <interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <confirmation:ConfirmationDialog/>
            </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </interactionRequest:PopupWindowAction>
    </interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But this will create a default WPF window, which is not metro-styled. How to change it to MahApps.Metro window?

And maybe, another way is to use MahApps.Metro Dialogs, but I have no idea how to use it with Prism.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, may be now you have to create a custom `confirmation:ConfirmationDialog` element :]

Comment: ConfirmationDialog is a UserControl, and it displays content of dialog. But this dialog is enclosed in a `Window`, which is created by Prism probably automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do two things, create new *MetroWindow* dialogs, then override the *PopupWindowAction* to use them. It sounds long winded but only takes 10 minutes:

So firstly, create your own Confirmation and Notification windows that inherit from *MetroWindow*, just like any other *MetroWindow*. You can copy the original Confirmation and Notification windows from the prism source and just change them as advised by the [mahapps quick start](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html).
So the Confirmation window would be something like:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyApp.DefaultPopupWindows.DefaultConfirmationWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
           MinWidth="300" MinHeight="150"
           Title="{Binding Title}" 
           BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"                      
           BorderThickness="1">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Content}"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button x:Name="OkButton" Content="OK" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="OkButton_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20,10,0,0" Click="CancelButton_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

And the associated code behind:

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp.DefaultPopupWindows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ConfirmationChildWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DefaultConfirmationWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of ConfirmationChildWindow.
        /// </summary>
        public DefaultConfirmationWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets or gets the <see cref="IConfirmation"/> shown by this window./>
        /// </summary>
        public IConfirmation Confirmation
        {
            get
            {
                return this.DataContext as IConfirmation;
            }
            set
            {
                this.DataContext = value;
            }
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Confirmation.Confirmed = true;
            this.Close();
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Confirmation.Confirmed = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Following on from this, you then create your own *PopupWindowAction* that extends the one in prism. Within that class you override the GetWindow function:

```
protected override Window GetWindow(INotification notification)
{
    MetroWindow wrapperWindow;

    if (this.WindowContent != null)
    {
        wrapperWindow = new MetroWindow();

        // If the WindowContent does not have its own DataContext, it will inherit this one.
        wrapperWindow.DataContext = notification;
        wrapperWindow.Title = notification.Title;

        this.PrepareContentForWindow(notification, wrapperWindow);
    }
    else
    {
        wrapperWindow = this.CreateDefaultWindow(notification);
    }

    return wrapperWindow;
}
```

You will also have to provide your own implementation for "CreateDefaultWindow" which will create your new *MetroWindow* version of the appropriate window:

```
protected new MetroWindow CreateDefaultWindow(INotification notification)
{
    MetroWindow window = null;

    if (notification is IConfirmation)
    {
        window = new DefaultPopupWindows.DefaultConfirmationWindow() { Confirmation = (IConfirmation)notification };
    }
    else
    {
        window = new DefaultPopupWindows.DefaultNotificationWindow() { Notification = notification };
    }

    return window;
}
```

Finally, within the *InteractionRequest* in your own view/window, you specify this new *PopupWindowAction*, rather than the prism version.

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks

Comment: This is very good already, but Krzysztof [suggests a solution](http://stuffleftatparty.com/prism-wpf-mahapps-modal-window-the-mvvm-way-part-2) that doesn’t require creating one’s own popup window. It’s sufficient to define a custom PopupWindowAction. I’ve used it and it works marvelously!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if yo can do it in prism 5.0 but with the new Prism 6.0 ([Github](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism)) you have a virtual method CreateWindow, you can subclass the PopupWindowAction and override it creating the Metro Window. I'm using the follwing code:

```
namespace KPP.Vision.Infrastructure.Interactions
{
    public class MetroPopupWindowAction:PopupWindowAction
    {

        protected override Window CreateWindow()
        {
            return new MetroPopupWindowView();

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and with these comments I could get a solution.
**I use Prism 6**

1) First of all rewrite the PopupWindowAction

```
/// <summary>
        ///     it creates a new metro window instead of a window
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override Window CreateWindow()
        {
            return new MetroPopupWindow();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a window with the notification type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="notification"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private new Window CreateDefaultWindow(INotification notification)
        {
            Window window = null;

            if (notification is IConfirmation)
            {
                window = new MetroConfirmationWindow {Confirmation = (IConfirmation) notification};
            }
            else
            {
                window = new MetroNotificationWindow {Notification = notification};
            }

            return window;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the window to display as part of the trigger action.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="notification">The notification to be set as a DataContext in the window.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override Window GetWindow(INotification notification)
        {
            Window wrapperWindow;

            if (WindowContent != null)
            {
                wrapperWindow = CreateWindow();

                if (wrapperWindow == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("CreateWindow cannot return null");

                // If the WindowContent does not have its own DataContext, it will inherit this one.
                wrapperWindow.DataContext = notification;
                wrapperWindow.Title = notification.Title;

                PrepareContentForWindow(notification, wrapperWindow);
            }
            else
            {
                wrapperWindow = CreateDefaultWindow(notification);
            }

            // If the user provided a Style for a Window we set it as the window's style.
            if (WindowStyle != null)
                wrapperWindow.Style = WindowStyle;

            return wrapperWindow;
        }
```

2) Create your MetroWindow, MetroNotificationWindow and your MetroConfirmationWindow [based in the default windows](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/9ab34dcae2b4daa9c830ebb33d3e0f79e6992636/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/DefaultPopupWindows)

Example:
**MetroPopupWindow.xaml**

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MetroPopupWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                          
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      mc:Ignorable="d"
                      Title="MetroPopupWindow" TitleCaps="False" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"
                        Content="{Binding Content}" />
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

**MetroNotificationWindow.xaml**

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MetroNotificationWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                          
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"                          
                      Title="Web Studio" TitleCaps="False" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"
                        Content="{Binding Content}" />
        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="{lex:Loc Ok}" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Click="OKButton_Click" IsDefault="True" />

    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

3) Change all references of PopupWindowAction for MetroPopupWindowAction
Example:

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <!-- Trigger listening for the "Raised" event on the source object (of type IInteractionRequest) -->
    <interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger
        SourceObject="{Binding SaveChangesConfirmationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <!-- That window will be show as a modal dialog and centered over this window -->
        <windowAction:MetroPopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" />
    </interactionRequest:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you don't need to do any custom stuff, nor use InteractionRequests.

You can check out MahApps.Metro.Demo.Samples (on [github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/develop/src/MahApps.Metro.Samples)) and check all preconfigured dialogs for MVVM ("Dialogs>Show InputDialog via VM", in this case).

It's pretty straightforward, you'll need to:
1) Register DialogCoordinator @ your bootstrapper (example with Autofac:)

```
builder.RegisterType<DialogCoordinator>().As<IDialogCoordinator>().SingleInstance();
```

2) Use an attached property in your Window to register your view model with the dialog sub-system. (This needs to be placed in the View.xaml of the ViewModel you want to call your dialog from:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.MyView"
             xmlns:dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             dialogs:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
             .../>
```

3) @ your ViewModel, make sure you have a readonly reference to the DialogCoordinator Interface, for Dependency Injection:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        readonly IDialogCoordinator _dialogCoordinator;

        public MyViewModel (IDialogCoordinator dcFromDependencyInjection)
        {
            _dialogCoordinator = dcFromDependencyInjection;
            [rest of your constructor code here]
        }
    }
}
```

4) Now, any time you need to call a dialog (InputDialog, ProgressDialog, MessageDialog, or even CustomDialog of your own) from your ViewModel you'll just need to:

```
async void MyInputDialog()
{
    await _dialogCoordinator.ShowInputAsync(this, "Dialog Title", "Dialog Message")
                            .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `PopupWindowAction` creates the window (with the value of `WindowContent` as its content), so you have to either change its implementation or write your own.